Where do I place my GitHub Action CI in my repo?
GitLab allows you to write CI into .gitlab-ci.yml. Where does Github store it's yaml file?

Github stores it's CI in a "workflow" file. This must be in the .github/workflows directory, and can have any name. All files in that directory have equal precedence. Your yaml must have a .yml or .yaml extension.
For more information see the documentation here:

About YAML syntax for workflows

